# Creating Dynamic Customer Name Drop Down base on Customer Status

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of customer table with active status (yes,no). And I gave the table name as tblCustomer.

[image]

What I am trying to do is to create a drop-down list in another sheet but that drop-down list should contain only Active Status "Yes" customers.

I created a name box like "ACustomer" and put this formula into Refers to:  `=OFFSET(tblCustomer[[#Headers],[Customer]],MATCH("Yes",tblCustomer[Active],0),0,COUNTIF(tblCustomer[Active],"Yes"),1)`

And create a drop-down list via Data Validation.
But I think the formula can't retread what I want.
See below image for what the formula generate.

[image]

It would be great if some of you suggest to work this out.

Comment: I'm not an expert on OFFSET or MATCH but I think that your pick-list formula is only returning the first 4 names because that is what the [HEIGHT] part of the formula (COUNTIF) is telling it to return. Also, the "MATCH" is only telling you where the first value is located (result=1).  I'm working on it b/c it's a fun problem so stay tuned.

Comment: Thank for your inputs anyway @Sam

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this,
Put this formula to "ACustomer" name box

```
=INDEX(tblCustomer, SMALL(IF("Yes"=tblCustomer[Active], ROW(tblCustomer[Active])-MIN(ROW(tblCustomer[Customer]))+1, ""), ROW(List!B1)),COLUMN(List!B1))
```

It won't show a list of drop-down but still showing each customer in each cell (one by one) but that customers have the active status "Yes".
If there are no customers with active status "Yes", the drop-down will show blank only. So I think it's still OK but not exactly what I expected.

[image]

Comment: Phyo - so, what does 'ROW(List!B1) do?